# Magento2 Zend Pdf draw png images not working

Tags: magento2, pdf, zend

I want to print png images in **pdf** not working

it gives error **Only non-interlaced images are currently supported**

how to solve this ?

```
$directImagePath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento232/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\fb8aff55bb3a38ad97f984d002bf3a6d\//c/o/cool-background1.png"
$image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($directImagePath);
```

Comment: While the issue might seem something big, the solution is pretty simple for Magento. All you have to do is switch from using PNG to JPEG.

Comment: i want to print the product images in the pdf, and i create extension for this so i need to print PNG images